# Получить позицию в RecyclerView через его адаптер

Tags: java, recyclerview, adapter

```html
for (int i = 0; i < tasksAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
  if (tasksAdapter.getItem(i).getId() == taskId)
    listTasks.smoothScrollToPosition(?????);
}
```

Как получить позицию найденного элемента в адаптере?

Comment: Вроде бы это будет просто `i`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так. И код получится по элегантнее.

```
// Получаем данные из адаптера
List<Task> tasks = taskAdapter.getTasks();
int index = tasks.indexOf(task);
listTasks.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ